# splunk query taking long time to return the value, can we eliminate append

Tags: query-optimization, splunk, splunk-query

i have initially  used inputlook to get the output and query was returning output in fractions of sec, but now i want to use the source as input and run the Splunk query but its taking lot of time to return output.

Please suggest solution to optimise the output time.
I am thinking of removing multiple append

```
index=csvlookups source="F:\\SplunkMonitor\\csvlookups\\Core_Network\\lookup_table_sip_pbx_usage.csv" OR source="F:\\SplunkMonitor\\csvlookups\\Core_Network\\lookup_table_dpt_capacity.csv" OR source="F:\\SplunkMonitor\\csvlookups\\Core_Network\\lookup_table_sip_pbx_forecasts.csv" 
| eval Date=strftime(strptime(Date,"%m/%d/%Y"),"%Y-%m-%d") 
| sort Date, CLLI 
| rename CLLI as Office 
| search Office="CLGRAB21DS1" 
| stats sum(Usage) as Usage by Office, Date 
| append 
    [ search index=csvlookups source="F:\\SplunkMonitor\\csvlookups\\Core_Network\\lookup_table_sip_pbx_usage.csv" OR source="F:\\SplunkMonitor\\csvlookups\\Core_Network\\lookup_table_dpt_capacity.csv" OR source="F:\\SplunkMonitor\\csvlookups\\Core_Network\\lookup_table_sip_pbx_forecasts.csv"
    | eval Date=strftime(strptime(Date,"%m/%d/%Y"),"%Y-%m-%d") 
    | reverse 
    | search Office="CLGRAB21DS1" AND Type="SIP PBX" 
    | fields Date NB_RTU 
    | fields - _raw _time ] 
| sort Date 
| fillnull value="CLGRAB21DS1" Office 
| filldown Usage 
| filldown NB_RTU 
| fillnull value=0 Usage 
| eval _time = strptime(Date, "%Y-%m-%d") 
| eval latest_time = if("now" == "now", now(), relative_time(now(), "now")) 
| where ((_time >= relative_time(now(), "-3y@h")) AND (_time <= latest_time)) 
| fields - latest_time Date 
| append 
    [ gentimes start=-1 
    | eval Date=strftime(mvrange(now(),now()+60*60*24*365*3,"1mon"),"%F") 
    | mvexpand Date 
    | fields Date 
    | append 
        [ search index=csvlookups source="F:\\SplunkMonitor\\csvlookups\\Core_Network\\lookup_table_sip_pbx_usage.csv" OR source="F:\\SplunkMonitor\\csvlookups\\Core_Network\\lookup_table_dpt_capacity.csv" OR source="F:\\SplunkMonitor\\csvlookups\\Core_Network\\lookup_table_sip_pbx_forecasts.csv"
        | rename "Expected Date of Addition" as edate 
        | eval edate=strftime(strptime(edate,"%m/%d/%Y"),"%Y-%m-%d") 
        | rename edate as "Expected Date of Addition" 
        | table Contact Customer "Expected Date of Addition" "Number of Channels" Switch 
        | reverse 
        | search Customer = "Regular Usage" AND Switch = "CLGRAB21DS1" 
        | rename "Number of Channels" as val 
        | return $val ] 
    | reverse 
    | filldown search 
    | rename search as Usage 
    | where Date != "" 
    | reverse 
    | append 
        [ search index=csvlookups source="F:\\SplunkMonitor\\csvlookups\\Core_Network\\lookup_table_sip_pbx_usage.csv" OR source="F:\\SplunkMonitor\\csvlookups\\Core_Network\\lookup_table_dpt_capacity.csv" OR source="F:\\SplunkMonitor\\csvlookups\\Core_Network\\lookup_table_sip_pbx_forecasts.csv"
        | rename "Expected Date of Addition" as edate 
        | eval edate=strftime(strptime(edate,"%m/%d/%Y"),"%Y-%m-%d") 
        | rename edate as "Expected Date of Addition" 
        | table Contact Customer "Expected Date of Addition" "Number of Channels" Switch 
        | reverse 
        | search Customer != "Regular Usage" AND Switch = "CLGRAB21DS1" 
        | rename "Expected Date of Addition" as Date 
        | eval _time=strptime(Date, "%Y-%m-%d") 
        | rename "Number of Channels" as Forecast 
        | stats sum(Forecast) as Forecast by Date] 
    | sort Date 
    | rename Switch as Office 
    | eval Forecast1 = if(isnull(Forecast),Usage,Forecast) 
    | fields - Usage Forecast 
    | streamstats sum(Forecast1) as Forecast 
    | fields - Forecast1 
    | eval Date=strptime(Date, "%Y-%m-%d") 
    | eval Date=if(Date < now(), now(), Date) ] 
| filldown Usage 
| filldown Office 
| eval Forecast = Forecast + Usage 
| eval Usage = if(Forecast >= 0,NULL,Usage) 
| eval _time=if(isnull(_time), Date, _time) 
| timechart limit=0 span=1w max(Usage) as Usage, max(NB_RTU) as NB_RTU, max(Forecast) as Forecast by Office 
| rename "NB_RTU: CLGRAB21DS1" as "RTU's Purchased", "Usage: CLGRAB21DS1" as "Usage", "Forecast: CLGRAB21DS1" as "Forecast" 
| filldown "RTU's Purchased" |sort -Forecast
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely an expensive query you don't want to run often or over large timeranges. In your first append, why are you using `reverse`? Are you trying to get latest time and earliest time which is why you used the append? You could use `earliest` and `latest` for this and eliminate the first subsearch. You could also consider `eventstats` instead of `stats` on that first search since you'll still retain the raw data.

You're also summing by _time, so you should think about binning your _time spans (i.e. | bin Date span=1h). Also, why are you using `filldown`? I'm guessing you want to grab values from different rows and need the rows to match? If so, use `streamstats` for this

Answer (score 0):

If `inputlookup` was working well you should stick with that as you won't get much faster.

It's hard to give specific advice about your query without knowing more about the data and your end goals.  In general:

Filter early.  Make your base query (before the first '|') as specific as possible.  Run your `where` and `search` clauses as soon as you can.

Use `fields` instead of `table`.  It's more efficient.

Sort only when necessary.  Usually, it's not necessary.

Fewer `appends` is better.